# How to put this command in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am quite new to powershell. I can run below command through command prompt and it works correctly.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\MAX\>nimax/report:fileName="C:\reports\my_file.htm";reportType="simple";Silent="false"
```

i am aware that when I put this into powershell I have to start with '&' but do i need to take care more at the command part `reportType="simple";Silent="false"`.

I am asking because I am not getting expected result (what i get when i run it from commandline)

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\MAX\>` this a prompt and not a command. And you don't need `&` if the command is just `nimax`

Comment: thanks for your comment and how should i put the extra part ? 
      *reportType="simple";Silent="false"*

Comment: issue soved, well new learning in powershell  :) `& "C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\MAX\nimax"/'REPORT:fileName="C:\reports\my_file.xml";''reportType="simple";''Silent="false"'`